# Tutorial Material Design

Tags: material-design

Tengo instalado Android Studio 3.1.3 (Powered by the Intellij Platform).

Estoy comenzando a hacer MDC-101 Android: Material Components (MDC) Basics (Java), es un tutorial
 que ofrece https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-101-java/#0  para aprender a 
 trabajar con Material Design

Se instala bien el proyecto de ejemplo, las dependencies o.k. Después el tutorial indica que
 se debe ejecutar la aplicación. Y ahí esta el problema, el botón Run, no aparece habilitado.
 Si voy a la barra de menú y clickeo en Run tengo habilitada la opción Run (Alt + Mayús + F10).
 Al ejecutar esa opción, me aparece una pequeña ventana que dice: Edit Configurations. Al hacer
 click en ella, aparece una ventana Run/Debug Configurations. Adjunto print de pantalla de lo 
 que indico.
 Por otra parte en el Event Log aparece:
 Migrate Project to Gradle?
 This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to uing the
 Gradle build system.

Si alguien ha desarrollado este tutorial o sabe cuál es el paso a seguir, lo agradecería.
 Estoy bastante confundido, y no sé que hacer para desarrollar el tutorial, en forma correcta.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Las imágenes:

[image: Edit configurations]

[image: Run/Debug Configurations]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución en este link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606504/cant-migrate-project-to-gradle-in-android-studio

Después, en mi caso, yo no importe el Proyecto. Si no que, instale el proyecto ya existente en el directorio.

Luego, Android solicito actualizar y listo.

Este es un excelente sitio para aprender del conocimiento que aportan los más experimentados.  Espero con el tiempo ser uno de aquellos...  Gracias.

Saludos a todos.